# c linux - memset raise Segmentation Fault in Release build, printf somehow can 'fix' it?

Tags: mysql, c, linux, libmysql

I'm getting segmentation fault on CentOS 7 64-bit, Release build (there's no issue in debug build)

I tried adding printf to locate where exactly the segfault happens, for below code, segfault raises at: `memset(len_p, 0, sizeof(*len_p));`

Also, If I add printf to print something right before memeset, there's no segfault, as if the printf is doing some magic here.

Please help me to understand the issue here.

[core dump](https://github.com/JerryYangJin/CoreDump/raw/master/core.4814) uploaded

Thanks a lot!

code snippet (mysql prepared statement to query something):

(this function was called couple of times, it doesn't always raise segfault)

```
int mysql_odb_read(void **data_p, size_t *len_p, git_otype *type_p, git_odb_backend *_backend, const git_oid *oid)
{
  MYSQL_BIND bind_buffers[2];
  MYSQL_BIND result_buffers[3];

  memset(bind_buffers, 0, sizeof(bind_buffers));

  // bind the repo passed to the statement
  bind_buffers[0].buffer = &(backend->mysql->repo);
  bind_buffers[0].buffer_length = sizeof(backend->mysql->repo);
  bind_buffers[0].length = &bind_buffers[0].buffer_length;
  bind_buffers[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;

  // bind the oid passed to the statement
  bind_buffers[1].buffer = (void*)oid->id;
  bind_buffers[1].buffer_length = 20;
  bind_buffers[1].length = &bind_buffers[1].buffer_length;
  bind_buffers[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB;

  if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(backend->mysql->odb_read, bind_buffers) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

  // execute the statement
  if (mysql_stmt_execute(backend->mysql->odb_read) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

  if (mysql_stmt_store_result(backend->mysql->odb_read) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

  if (mysql_stmt_num_rows(backend->mysql->odb_read) == 1) {

    memset(result_buffers, 0, sizeof(result_buffers));

    result_buffers[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_TINY;
    result_buffers[0].buffer = type_p;
    result_buffers[0].buffer_length = sizeof(*type_p);
    result_buffers[0].is_null = 0;
    result_buffers[0].length = &result_buffers[0].buffer_length;
    memset(type_p, 0, sizeof(*type_p));

    result_buffers[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
    result_buffers[1].buffer = len_p;
    result_buffers[1].buffer_length = sizeof(*len_p);
    result_buffers[1].is_null = 0;
    result_buffers[1].length = &result_buffers[1].buffer_length;
    printf("len_p:%lu\n",*len_p);//if i remove this printf call, there will be segfault
    memset(len_p, 0, sizeof(*len_p));

    result_buffers[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG_BLOB;
    result_buffers[2].buffer = *data_p;
    result_buffers[2].is_null = 0;
    result_buffers[2].buffer_length = data_len;
    result_buffers[2].length = &data_len;
    //memset(&data_len, 0, sizeof(data_len));

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(backend->mysql->odb_read, result_buffers) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

    error = mysql_stmt_fetch(backend->mysql->odb_read);

    if (data_len > 0) {
      *data_p = malloc(data_len);
      if(*data_p){
    result_buffers[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG_BLOB;
        result_buffers[2].buffer = *data_p;
    result_buffers[2].is_null = 0;
        result_buffers[2].buffer_length = data_len;
    result_buffers[2].length = &data_len;
      if (mysql_stmt_fetch_column(backend->mysql->odb_read, &result_buffers[2], 2, 0) != 0)
             return GIT_ERROR;
      }
      else{
        printf("odb_read, malloc returned NULL\n");
        return GITERR_NOMEMORY;
      }
    }

    error = GIT_OK;
  } else
    error = GIT_ENOTFOUND;

  // free result
  if (mysql_stmt_free_result(backend->mysql->odb_read) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

  mysql_free_result(meta_result);

  // reset the statement for further use
  if (mysql_stmt_reset(backend->mysql->odb_read) != 0)
      return GIT_ERROR;

  return error;
}
```

Comment: `printf` is not doing any magic :) .... delay introduced by printf() helps for proper output may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell the exact problem without dumps or other informations, but a possible explanation may be that the `len_p` is a dangling pointer.

This triggers the segfault, however, by calling `printf`, you are probably filling up the stack area where `len_p` is pointing, with `printf` data, hence remapping the pointer with a new value, avoiding the segmentation fault.

Comment: thank you, @jndok ! I'll investigate more and update

Comment: Hi, @jndok, i uploaded the [core dump](https://github.com/JerryYangJin/CoreDump/raw/master/core.4814), please let me know if you want the whole source code, thanks!

Comment: Hi, @jndok, i used [gdb backtrace](https://gist.github.com/JerryYangJin/264ffd8a14cd0b6f0307) on one of the core dump, not sure if this would help